# If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes such that $p|c$ and $q|c$, prove that $pq|c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes such that $p|c$ and $q|c$, prove that $pq|c$ ..

I start with this:

if $c=pk$  and $c=qt$
then $q|pk$ and $p|qt$

but a couldn't get the solution.

I need your help

Comment: Observe that gcd(p,q)=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $q|pk$ and as $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes we must have gcd$(p,q)=1$ and hence Euclid's Lemma allows us to conclude $q|k$. Hence $k=ql$ and then $c=pk=pql$, or $pq|c$.